# .equalSpacing in UIStackView not working properly with CustomView

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview, custom-view, snapkit

I have created a custom view of checkbox / radio button that animates when checked and unchecked. Problem is when I embed the custom view to a stackView that is **.equalSpacing** the button cannot be tapped anymore, my guess is the borderView(which has the tap gesture) shrink too small so it cannot be tapped.

Strange though is the borderView can be still be  seen even if it really shrunk.

If it is **.fillEqually** and **.fillProportionally** it works properly.

I am using SnapKit for arranging constraints.

Let me know if I should paste the whole code here.

## Custom View

```
public final class CustomView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private let borderedView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return view
    }()
    
    private var errorStackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.isHidden = true
        return sv
    }()
    
    private var borderStackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        return sv
    }()
    
    private var parentStackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        return sv
    }()

.
.
.
.
.


// MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    public init(button: ButtonType) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

.
.
.
.
.
.

     private func setupUI() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        borderedView.addSubview(disabledImageView)
        
        borderedView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.height.equalTo(borderSize)
        }
        
        borderStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [borderedView, label])
        borderStackView.spacing = 12
        borderStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        
        borderStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.height.width.equalTo(borderSize)
        }

        
        errorStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [errorIconImageView, inlineErrorLabel])
        errorStackView.spacing = 7
        errorStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        
        parentStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [borderStackView, errorStackView])
        parentStackView.axis = .vertical
        parentStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        addSubview(parentStackView)

        parentStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp.centerY)
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        disabledImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make
                .leading
                .trailing
                .top
                .bottom
                .height
                .width
                .equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        parentStackView.sizeToFit()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

.
.
.
.
.
.
    // MARK: - Action
    
    public func addAction(action: @escaping ((Bool?) -> Void)) {
        borderedView.addGestureRecognizerOnView(target: self, #selector(handleTapGesture(sender:)))
        status = action
    }
}
```

## View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private lazy var checkboxDefault: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleUnchecked()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkboxEnabledAndChecked: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleChecked()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkboxDisableAndUnchecked: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleDisabledAndUnchecked()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkboxDisableAndChecked: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleDisabledAndChecked()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkboxError: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleError()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()
    
    private lazy var checkboxMultilineError: CustomView = {
        let checkbox = CustomView()
        checkbox.addAction { [weak self] checkboxStatus in
            self?.handleMultiError()
        }
        return checkbox
    }()

.
.
.
.
.
.
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        let stackview = UIStackView(
            arrangedSubviews: [
                checkboxDefault,
                checkboxEnabledAndChecked,
                checkboxDisableAndUnchecked,
                checkboxDisableAndChecked,
                checkboxError,
                checkboxMultilineError
            ])
        
        stackview.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackview.axis = .vertical

        view.addSubview(stackview)

        stackview.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.center.equalTo(view.snp.center)
            make.width.equalTo(300)
            make.height.equalTo(300)
        }
}
```

Comment: I get conflicting constraints even without putting `CustomView` inside a stack view (by just setting `frame` and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`). Do you get that as well?

Comment: If all you are asking about is a checkbox with a label, you should remove the parts of your code that are about `errorStackView` or `inlineErrorLabel` or stuff like that. Make a [mcve]. "Minimal" is the keyword.

Comment: @Sweeper I include those since it is a content of my stackView so others can see what is inside the parentStackView and other stackViews.

Comment: If the views are important to the question, include them in the picture of the checkbox, so that it is clear what kind of layout you are trying to achieve. Right now it is unclear why you are using these nested stack views to get a simple checkbox + label. If it is not related to the question, remove it from the code snippet. Remember that _you_ are responsible for coming up with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding intrinsicContentSize in Custom View

and adding invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() everytime the view should be updated. In my case it was in **handleTapGesture**

```
// MARK: - Lifecycle

    public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
    }
.
.
.
.
.
// MARK: - Action
    
    @objc private func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() // Call this when custom view needs to be updated
    }
```